# rails button_to type="button"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Basically, what I am trying to get dropdown button from rails button_to, this is done via ajax, when someone clicks on that button, it shows rendered cart `<ul>` tag via ajax render.

bootstrap:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> <span class="badge"><%="#{@cart.line_items_count}" %></span></button>
```

rails button_to:

```
%= button_to navbar_cart_path, {remote :true, method: :get, :class => 'btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle', data_toggle: "dropdown"}  do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
          <span class="badge" id="cart-badge-id"><%="#{@cart.line_items_count}" %></span>
      <% end %>
```

This generates similar button tags, except when looking at html source code, bootstrap button has attribute type="button", but rails generates type="submit"

bootstrap:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type = "button" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span> <span class="badge">5</span></button>
```

rails:

```
<form class="button_to" method="get" action="/navbar_cart data-remote="true">
  <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" data_toggle="dropdown" type="submit">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
          <span class="badge" id="cart-badge-id">5</span>
</button></form>
```

Another great question if whether or not it is even possible to even make a dropdown menu this way.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a drop down you could use `select_tag('attr', options_for_select())` to get your drop down and then do something like this to kick off any ajax stuff you want to do:

```
$('#my_select_dropdown').change(function(){
  //do stuff here
});
```

EDIT: Here is a link to look at `select_tag` docs in case you want more details: http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag

Comment: No, I want to make dropdown menu where I have my cart products listed, image, quantity, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Just override the type attribute in the *html_options* argument of the method which is the same hash you are passing the class name for your element:

```
  <%= button_to navbar_carth_path, {remote: true, method: :get}, {"class": "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle": "dropdown", "type": "button"}  do %>
```

I think yo were also adding the *html options* within the same hash as the *options* hash which are not the same, the options hash (the first) are options for the rails helper per se, the second hash corresponds to attribute values that you want to apply to the rendered element:

```
button_to(name = nil, options = nil, html_options = nil, &block)
```

Check the signature of the method [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to).

**Update** You were also passing the `remote :true` parameter wrong, you have a space between the remote word and the actual value so it parses as a symbol, it should be: `remote: true`. On the other hand, I advice to enclose all html options of helpers (like `data-toggle`) between quotes and not only its values so that you can use hyphens instead of dashes (bootstrap option is `data-toggle` AFAIK, not `data_toggle`

Comment: Yeah, already tryed it. It doesnt override or change anything, does it work for you?

Comment: @marisancans Yes it does, please see my updated answer

Comment: Hey, changed the code like you said:<%= button_to navbar_cart_path, {"type": "button", method: :get, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", "data-toggle": "dropdown", type: "button"}  do %>
              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
              <span class="badge" id="cart-badge-id"><%="#{@cart.line_items_count}" %></span>
          <% end %>  data-toggle now works correctly, but type isnt changing, when I write someting like "typex" then in changes. Maybe its not possible to overwrite?

Comment: Theres duplication of  type: "button", removed that too doesnt work

Comment: Did you noticed that I'm passing two different hashes as arguments to the method, did you checked the link for the method signature? Take a look again at my snippet and you'll see its not the same.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like when using rails button_to and adding data: attributes doesnt overwrite type="button", so I tryed experimanting and came up with this.

```
<%= link_to navbar_cart_path, { method: :get, remote: true, class: "btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle", "id": "cart-button", "type": "button", "data-toggle": "dropdown" }  do %>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
          <span class="badge" ><%="#{@cart.line_items_count}" %></span>
      <% end %>
```

This generates HTML code:

```
a class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" id="cart-button" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-remote="true" data-method="get" href="/navbar_cart">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
          <span class="badge" >5</span>
```

Where I can then use AJAX GET to render @cart partial in dropdown  tags